# Query on Many to Many tables with multiple OR/AND

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

I have a basic many-to-many table that is:

```
tbFilter
filterId | filterName


tbProduct
productId | productName


tbProductFilter
filterId | productId
```

So, I have many products with many filters (colors, sizes, etc). Now, I need to create a procedure to finde products with some filter combination, like:
All products that is(blue OR green) and (large OR xlarge) and (forMen)

The only way that I found to create this query is with multiple joins of same table, each join for a "group" filter or with multiples subqueries, each one for a group. The biggest problem is that the many-to-many table have more them 100k records, so this approaches give a poor performance.

How is the best way to do this query? I'm using sql 2012.

Thanks

This is how I get working now:

```
select [produtos].* FROM [dbo].[tbProdutos] AS [produtos] JOIN [dbo].tbJuncaoProdutoCategoria] AS [juncaoProdutoCategoria] ON [produtos].[produtoId] = juncaoProdutoCategoria].[produtoId] JOIN [dbo].[tbJuncaoProdutoCategoria] AS juncaoProdutoCategoria2] ON [produtos].[produtoId] = [juncaoProdutoCategoria2].[produtoId] JOIN [dbo].[tbProdutoCategoria] AS [produtoCategoria] ON [produtoCategoria].[categoriaId] = [juncaoProdutoCategoria].[categoriaId] where [juncaoProdutoCategoria].categoriaId = 1 AND ([juncaoProdutoCategoria2].categoriaId = 300 OR [juncaoProdutoCategoria2].categoriaId = 301)
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables?  Also, can you show what query you are attempting for this example?

Comment: I just sent the query that I'm using right now. What I'm looking is a better approach that I dont need to make a join in each filter "group"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the filters into a table (or a table-valued parameter), join that to the ProductFilter table, group by product, and count the unique filters that get joined.

This method can handle an arbitrary number of filters and perform fuzzy matching, i.e. "show me the products that match three of these four filters"

```
DECLARE @filterCount int = 3
DECLARE @filterSet TABLE ( filterNum int, filterName varchar(max) )

INSERT @filterSet VALUES
  (1,'blue'),(1,'green'),
  (2,'large'),(2,'xlarge'),
  (3,'forMen')

SELECT pf.ProductId
FROM tbProductFilter pf
INNER JOIN tbFilter f ON f.filterId = pf.filterId
INNER JOIN @filterSet s ON s.filterName = f.filterName
GROUP BY pf.productId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.filterNum) = @filterCount
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a quick test and I think that this will work exactly like I need. I will transform in a SP and make some performance tests!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you most certainly want to check your indexing - you'll want indexes on all foreign key fields, as well as on the fitlerName.

Assuming your indexing is in good shape, here's one way you might do this:

```
SELECT p.*       -- preferably just select the fields you need here...
FROM products p
WHERE p.productId IN (
    SELECT pf.product_id
    FROM tbProductFilter pf
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbFilter f 
                  WHERE pf.filterId = f.filterId AND f.filterName IN ('blue', 'green'))
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbFilter f 
                  WHERE pf.filterId = f.filterId AND f.filterName IN ('large', 'xlarge'))
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbFilter f 
                  WHERE pf.filterId = f.filterId AND f.filterName = 'forMen')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! This multiples where is better them multiples join on tbProductFilter?

Comment: It may - only with trying it out and/or seeing the query plan can this be determined absolutely.